# Call a function with SKAction ever X seconds Swift

Tags: ios, swift, skaction

I have a two functions that spawn enemies into the GamePlay scene. I tried calling them every .3 seconds with NSTimers, but when the app lost focus, the timers would keep going and spawn hundreds of enemies.

I read that SKActions automatically pause, so I tried to implement one but I am getting an error saying:

Cannot invoke 'repeatActionForever' with an argument list of type '(SKAction!)'

Cannot invoke 'runBlock' with an argument list of type '((), queue: (Double))'

Code:

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

superblockRandomizer = NSTimeInterval(arc4random_uniform(5) + 5)
runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence(SKAction.runBlock(spawnEnemies(), queue: (0.3)))))
runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence(SKAction.runBlock(spawnSuperBlocks(), queue: (superblockRandomizer)))))
}
```

The two functions I would like to run are spawnEnemies and spawnSuperBlocks. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:
It spawns the superblock right when the scene moves to view. Heres the code I've got for the superblock

```
    let spawnSuperBlock = SKAction.sequence([SKAction.runBlock(spawnSuperBlocks), SKAction.waitForDuration(superblockRandomizer)])
    runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(spawnSuperBlock))
```

Shouldn't it wait at least superblockRandomizer time before spawning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are `SKAction` methods that does nothing but does a time delay. For instance, you can create a `SKAction.sequence` containing the action you desire to be executed, and a delay of the 0.3 seconds:

```
let action = SKAction.sequence([SKAction.runBlock(spawnEnemies), SKAction.waitForDuration(0.3)])
```

Then, like you tried before, you can make the action run forever:

```
runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(action))
```

The result is a endlessly occurring `spawnEnemies` that runs every 0.3 seconds.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much bro. I spent so much time trying to figure out how to pause NSTimers and I could have just done this. Thanks a ton

Comment: It is spawning the superblocks right when the scene starts, not after the superblockrandomizer time.

Comment: I don't know how you implemented the rest of your code. If you want this action to start only after `superblockrandomizertime`, you can nest it in another sequence where you have a `SKAction.waitForDuration(superblockrandomizertime)` to stall it for some more time.

Comment: I edited the OP, shouldnt it wait at least for the superblockRandomizer time?

Comment: All I can gather from what you've said is that you want methods called periodically, and that the period is 0.3 seconds. I am unclear about what superblockrandomizer time is for.

Comment: Basically, after superBlockRandomizer seconds, a larger block spawns that goes faster than the other blocks. However, right when the scene is shown, the superBlock spawns. I want it to wait to spawn until at least superblockRandomizer seconds have passed.

Comment: So for superBlocks, 1 spawns immediately as you enter the scene. Thereafter it waits superBlockRandomizer time before spawning again, this time continuously at a 0.3 second interval?

Comment: Yes, 1 spawns immediately which it shouldn't. I want the superBlocks to spawn ever superblockRandomizer seconds. Say superblockRandomizer = 6 for the first instance. So one spawns 6 seconds after the scene moved to view, then the next one at 6+superblockRandomizer seconds etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84505/discussion-between-kelvin-lau-and-darkstar).